# Wordpress theme breaking when loaded in https

Tags: php, css, wordpress, sass

I'm trying to help make the security of my company's website more up to snuff by making the default load https, however loading it in https breaks the theme. [Like so.](https://www.missionstl.org)

The error it gives is the following:

```
Warning: filemtime() [function.filemtime]: stat failed for https://www.missionstl.org/wp-content/themes/LivingOS-Grow/sass/style.scss.php in /nfs/c10/h03/mnt/175782/domains/missionstl.org/html/wp-content/themes/LivingOS-Grow/wp-sass/wp-sass.php on line 127
```

The line in question is the following:

> // update cache creation time
>   $full_cache[ 'updated' ] = filemtime( $sass_path );

For a bit of context, I am not the original web developer for this website, nor did the previous developer leave *any* notes in particular. The style code is all sass generated which has made trying to go in and edit it a pain. I'm still learning PHP so trying to figure this out is a bit of a pain.

The full wp-sass.php can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ruaaud2sf06phlp/wp-sass.php?dl=0

Any help that can be given would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: can suggest checking the path to the css, make sure it's pointing to https:// not http://

Comment: you shouldn't be doing `stat` on a url anyways. stat is intended for low level filesystem information, which invariably is utterly unavailable or outright wrong when accessed via http

Comment: @MarcB Again, I'm not the one who chose this theme and I don't really know how to go in and change it without breaking everything, which is not an option.

Comment: @Aaron Any idea where I might find that?

Comment: @Alex should be linked in the header.php document.